# How to p4 reconcile and p4 submit in Jenkins groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, perforce

There is an option to run p4 reconcile via Jenkins pipeline and if there where made changes to submit them(p4 publish)?

realization examples if you have some please

Edit:

my question is how to run in p4 reconcile on my workspace and then if there made changes to submit them. according to [p4 plugin for jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/P4+Plugin) which allows "Submit assets back to Perforce Helix (Publish)" (thats why i wrote p4 publish and meant p4 submit) but they didn't mentioned p4 reconcile.

I'm using the following in my code which sync the latest version files in stream workspace:

```
line_ending = isUnix()  ? 'UNIX' : 'WIN'
checkout([
    $class: 'PerforceScm', 
    credential: '*****************************',
    filter: [[$class: 'FilterPathImpl', path: '//Automation']],
    populate: [$class: 'AutoCleanImpl', delete: false, modtime: false, parallel: [enable: false, minbytes: '1024', minfiles: '1', path: '/usr/local/bin/p4', threads: '4'], pin: '', quiet: true, replace: true], 
    workspace: [$class: 'ManualWorkspaceImpl', charset: 'none', name: "JENKINS-${NODE_NAME}", pinHost: false, spec: [allwrite: false, clobber: false, compress: false, line: line_ending, locked: true, modtime: false, rmdir: true, 
    streamName: '//<Stream_name>/name/...', 
    view: """
<Depot_path_to_sync>/...\t//JENKINS-${NODE_NAME}/<Depot_path_to_sync>/...
<Depot_path_to_sync>/...\t//JENKINS-${NODE_NAME}/<Depot_path_to_sync>/..."""]]
])
```

didn't tried to the submit via jenkins yet but i could find documentation on it so i will probably handle it, but, for reconcile I couldn't find so i asked for a reconcile example from someone here. I believe that it comes with submit so it may shortage my debugging time.

Comment: What is your question, precisely? Have you tried something, and it didn't work the way you expected? What did you try? What did it do? What did you expect it to do? There is no `p4 publish` command; what do you think that command, if it existed, would do?

Comment: I've edited the main question @BryanPendleton

Answer (score 0):

It's probably going to be easiest for you to develop the list of commands to run **outside** of Jenkins first, where it's easier for you to experiment and try different things.

**Then** work on automating your commands in Jenkins.

`p4 reconcile` compares the current state of your workspace on your client machine against the head revisions of the files that you have mapped, and opens the necessary files for add/edit/delete/move/etc.

Subsequently, you separately issue `p4 submit` to submit those changed files to the server.

Honestly, this isn't commonly a thing that people automate in this way, so perhaps you could explain more about **why** you think you want to do this.

Using the 'reconcile' approach to tracking changes in your source code is useful for interactive developers, who may roam around in their source tree, e.g., using their IDE, and make various changes, then later, when they feel like they are ready to submit their changes, they run `p4 reconcile` to let the Perforce server figure out what files they actually changed during their interactive editing session.

And people typically use Jenkins to automate their shared build/test environments, not to automate the tasks performed by individual developers.

So automated Jenkins tasks are typically very certain about what files they changed, because those automated tasks make the exact same changes each time (they're automated, after all).

Therefore, an automated Jenkins task typically uses the `p4 edit` command to tell the server that it's changing a file, then it makes whatever change is necessary, then it uses the `p4 submit` command to submit that change.

Comment: Thank you first of all. I'm applying the build procedure in a way that when specific files has been changed during the build then i want to submit them. if my build has been failed, those files are not even created.

Answer (score 0):

I setup project to build and to publish using jenkins pipeline with perforce

p4publish do p4 reconcile and then do p4 submit.
You can see the log.

Comment: as far as i read and saw way of use, p4publish is for submit command. but couldn't find p4 reconcile command. can you attach a working example please?